# Ruby sort array of hashes by specific requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to sort array of hashes:

```
resource = [{ 'resource_id' => 34,
         'description' => 'NR00123',
         'total_gross_amount_cents' => bank_transfer.amount_cents,
         'contractor_name' => 'Bogisich Inc' },
       { 'resource_id' => 35,
         'description' => bank_transfer.purpose,
         'total_gross_amount_cents' => 54321,
         'contractor' => 'Bogisich Inc' },
       { 'resource_id' => 36,
         'description' => 'Some description 2',
         'total_gross_amount_cents' => 0123,
         'contractor' => bank_transfer.creditor_name
        }
       ]
```

By following requirements:

first - match_invoice_number

```
  def match_invoice_number(resource)
    bank_transfer.purpose&.include?(resource['description'])
  end
```

second - match_amount

```
  def match_amount(resource)
    bank_transfer.amount_cents == resource['total_gross_amount'] || resource['gross_amount_cents']
  end
```

third - match_vendor

```
  def match_vendor(resource)
    resource['contractor'].include?(bank_transfer.creditor_name)
  end
```

So at the end resource should be like:

```
resource = [
  { 'resource_id' => 35,
    'description' => bank_transfer.purpose,
    'total_gross_amount_cents' => 54_321,
    'contractor' => 'Bogisich Inc' },
  { 'resource_id' => 34,
    'description' => 'NR00123',
    'total_gross_amount_cents' => bank_transfer.amount_cents,
    'contractor_name' => 'Bogisich Inc' },
  { 'resource_id' => 36,
    'description' => 'Some description 2',
    'total_gross_amount_cents' => 0o123,
    'contractor' => bank_transfer.creditor_name }
]
```

I was trying to use `select` but the end resource looks the same like at the beginning. Here what I use:

```
  def only_suggested(resource)
    resource.select do |resource|
      collection(resource)
    end
  end

  def collection(resource)
    [match_invoice_number(resource), match_amount(resource), match_vendor(resource)]
  end
```

Comment: `resource`is an array, so what is `resource['description']`?

Comment: array of hashes as you see

Comment: What I meant is that [Array#\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) cannot have an argument that is a string.

Answer (score 0):

`collection(resource)` method returns an array which treated as `true` value when `select` checks it, so you get your entire collection back. To sort you can use `sort_by` method. If you need to uplift an item that follows all conditions use `all?` method:

```
resource.sort_by do |resource|
  collection(resource).all? ? 0 : 1 # To return sortable value
end
```

If conditions have different priorities:

```
resource.sort_by do |resource|
  if match_invoice_number(resource)
    0
  elsif match_amount(resource)
    1
  elsif match_vendor(resource)
    2
  else
    3
  end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't need to met all conditions, read my post first. I will get an empty array with your solution.

Comment: It will crash when there will be no match - to avoid this you will need to add another elsif with score 4 which is not good because it will return undesirable `resource` at the end. When you will have e.g. 100 `resources` you won't be able to recognize which are matched because it will return all collection.

Comment: It has `else` statement with a score of 3 to return if nothing matches.